# How to configure PMD to only give Blocker warnings?

Tags: java, eclipse, pmd

I like the way you can tune FindBugs to warn you about only the most pressing problems.  Then as you fix things you can lower it.  This way you don't get overwhelmed by warnings.

[image]

I'm trying to do something similar with PMD.  I went to PMD > Rule Configuration, ordered the items by Priority and only selected Blocker.  Re-ran it but it still finds tons of stuff, not limited to only Blocker category.

[image]

How can I limit PMD in Eclipse to only show me Blocker warnings?

Comment: Did you clear the previously found warnings before the rerun?